# Facing problem while committing from Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, git, bonobo

I have to upgrade one of my SDK while doing so after replacing SDK with new upgraded files it is working fine but when trying to push the same on remote that time I am facing the problem. In commit, it is taking only modified files only and some files are showing out of source control. Also, don't know what is the meaning of the (!) symbol. Can someone help with this? Please forgive me for bad English. Thanks in advance.[image: As shown in image only modified files are considering to commit]

Comment: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.2/svn.ref.svn.c.status.html

Found the meaning of all the symbols but still haven't got how to commit.

Comment: `!` means an Item is missing (e.g. you moved or deleted), try deleting the files and add them again, after that hit `git add .` and then commit